# Symfony 3 Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I'm have this address form. Everything is working as expected, until I added a drop down selection field for the cities. I'm getting this error when I try to save the form:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Address could not be converted to string

The docs say that the EntityType field is designed to load options from a Doctrine entity.

This is the form:

```
 $builder
             ->add('cities', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => \AppBundle\Entity\Cities::class,
                'choice_label' => 'cityname',
                'choice_value' => 'cityid')
            )
```

And this is my entity

```
 /**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="cities", type="string", length=55, nullable=false)
 */
private $cities;
```

And setters/getters:

```
 /**
 * Set cities
 *
 * @param string $cities
 *
 * @return Address
 */
public function setCities($cities)
{
    $this->cities = $cities;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cities
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCities()
{
    return $this->cities;
}
```

I also added this:

```
public function __toString() {
  return $this->getCities();
}
```

And had this result:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Method AppBundle\Entity\Address::__toString()
>   must return a string value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should implement `__toString()` method for you Entity:

> __toString() allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string. For example, what echo $obj; will print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR level error is emitted.

For example, you could write something like this to represent your class as a string:

```
public function __toString() {
  return $this->getCities();
}
```

More info about this **magic method** [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).

Comment: Forgot to mention I already did that. I got an error. I think the EntityType is an array: '1'=>'New York'

Comment: @DaniCalifornia I also don't like this notation:  'class' => \AppBundle\Entity\Cities::class. Try this one:  'class' => 'AppBundle:Cities'.

Comment: Same error: Catchable Fatal Error: Method AppBundle\Entity\Address::__toString() must return a string value

Comment: What do you have in your __toString() method?

Comment: return $this->getCities();

Comment: Try explicit type convertion `(string)$this->getCities();`

Comment: That gives me an error: __toString() must not throw an exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159779/discussion-between-azuloo-and-dani-california).

Comment: Hi. I'm using `public function __toString() { return (string) $this->name; }` and `public function getName() { return $this->__toString(); }` You can try that too.

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. I used _toString() method in my cities class (where I'm supposed to save the city), but did not use it in my other entity (where the cities are saved).... I'm marking this as an answer because you were right all along (in the chat, you constantly asked me about that method.)

Comment: @DaniCalifornia I'm glad you've worked this out :D But you know what - that wasn't a waste of time because: 1. You will never ever made this mistake after his situation and 2. You've learn about `AdminController` which you can override and use it for your own sake.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your toString method is returning something other than a string (possibly an array going by the name?). You might want to try inspecting the data to identify what data type it is.

Better than using toString though is the [choice_label](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label) option - this tells Symfony what property from the entity should be mapped to the label.

Comment: But I'm using EntityType and I alreay set the choice_label

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see that! Is `cityname` present in your entity - I don't see it in the example? And if so, is it a string?